# Covid Correlation Coefficients

Tags: statistics, correlation

New to statistics. Reading a intro book. I just finished a chapter on Correlation Coefficients, and I'm going over covid data. I think I grasp the relevant formula, but I think I'm making some mistakes in interpretation and possibly application.

Using data from Our World in Data's Covid data I used Excel to calculate correlation coefficients. So for total covid cases per capita in USA vs. total covid deaths per capital I'm getting a CC of 0.97. That makes sense, people aren't dying of Covid without having acquired Covid first.

Some weird things I'm getting, negative CCs for total covid cases per capita vs. hospitalizations per capita (-.389) or vs. icu admissions (-.606).

Now OWID's hospital and icu data is current admissions which rises and falls, but the total cases per capital just keeps going up. Now I'd expect a loose correlation since total cases goes back to 2020, but what really matters for hosp/icu is current state of affairs. Still, why would either be negatively correlated and why would the CC be so far away from zero? I'd expect the values to be positive since if the total is increasing rapidly, the number of hospitalizations will also be rising.

I suspect I'm misinterpreting the information.

Comment: *Why* a correlation or negative correlation exists is really a modeling question, not a math question.  You are likely to have more luck asking epidemiologists or public health experts.  I have some *speculations*, but I have no expertise in these areas, and would prefer *not* to post an answer which is almost certain to be wrong.  I would encourage others on this site who lack the relevant background to similarly avoid speculative answers.  Talk to a real expert.

Comment: It is possible that the folk at [biology.se] might know more.  There may also be a political aspect to it ([politics.se]).

Comment: Just ran the numbers on new cases percapita vs. icu/hospitalizations. I'm getting something reasonable there, 0.64 vs. 0.82. I'd expect a relatively high, positive correlation since new cases is roughly the current number of infections. Further hospitalizations is more closely correlated than ICU admissions. I think Xander Henderson is on to something. I'm thinking hospitalizations is roughly proportional to the derivative of the total number of cases hence 0.82, rather than the total. In other words $A'(x)$ can be highly correlated to $B(x)$ but $A(x)$ can still be anti-correlated to $B(x)$.

Comment: Your $0.97$ or something similarly high is almost inevitable: you have taken two times series showing cumulative numbers so both are increasing at the same time and are thus highly correlated.  You would also get positive correlation for example if you took cumulative Covid cases and cumulative births since January 2020 even though the two are essentially unrelated.

Comment: A better comparison would be to not use a cumulative indicator so instead "new Covid cases in the last week/month" and "new Covid deaths in the last week/month": you would presumably still get a positive correlation though smaller, and it would make more sense.   Each of these might also be better related to your hospitalizations per capita and ICU admissions  per capita data.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you actually have a problem.  Something those new to statistics very often overlook when considering correlation coefficients is the effect of degrees of freedom.  A CC of 0.97 is not very significant if you only have 4 or 5 pairs in your sample whereas one of 0.64 is massively significant if you have more than 100 pairs (still significant at the 0.05% level if you have only 20 pairs).

I suggest you try & find a book of statistical tables to give you a feel for degrees of freedom  You should also take a good look at the theory behind the statistical tests you want to use - they all have conditions & catches.

Comment: Like I said in response to the original question, I don't think that this is a mathematical question.  Assuming that the negative correlation is real and significant, the mathematics only tell us that there *is* a relationship.  It doesn't tell us *why*.  This comes down to understanding epidemiology and public policy well enough to come up with an explanation.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "modeling" issue, @Xander Henderson? I think between you and Henry an answer is coalescing in my mind. I think its only necessary to prove that there exists $f(x)$, $g(x)$ such that 0.5<CORR(f'(x),g(x))<1.0 and CORR( f(x),g(x))<0.

Comment: I can think of several reasons why COVID cases and hospitalizations or ICU visits would go down.  It could be a detection issue (better detection means more cases, but more minor cases which don't lead to hospitalization), or the effectiveness of vaccines, or people *refusing* to go to the hospital out of fear of complications.  There are *many* reasons why there might be a negative correlation.  Mathematics can't really help you come up with these explanations---it can only help you to decide whether or not they are significant *after* you identify them in your model.